# KIVY : BoxLayout containing horizontal BoxLayout

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy

Am trying to have 4 `Horizontal` box layout stacked in a BoxLayout in a vertical way.

[image: Rough Sketch]

My KV file :

```
<HBoxWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        id: boxlayout_h
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Image:
            source: '/Users/driftking9987/Desktop/fp.gif'
<VBoxWidget1>:
    BoxLayout:
        spacing: 10
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: [1,.25]
        pos: root.pos
        Label:
            text: "Status : "
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Label:
            text: "Pending"
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Widget:


<ContainerBox>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    HBoxWidget:
    VBoxWidget1:
```

I planned to have multiple `VBoxWidget` in a vertical way but it's just not working out.

Moreover to achieve the `[9] Label`, I thought I will have a `BoxLayout` with 2 rows, in horizontal, 2nd row will have the above mentioned properties. But this is just not working out. Below is what am getting. I tried setting the `size_hint` as `1,.25` i.e the whole area will be divided into 4 parts but it's not giving the desired result.

PY File :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class HBoxWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HBoxWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class VBoxWidget1(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VBoxWidget1, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ContainerBox() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this: I changed HBOX and VBOX widget to BoxLayout and added Label and another BoxLayouts to ContainerBox. It looks quite like on your drawing

[image]

```
<HBoxWidget>:

    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: 'center'
        anchor_y: 'center'
        Image:
            source: 'duck.jpg'
<VBoxWidget1>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "horizontal"
        size: [1,.25]
        pos: root.pos
        Label:
            text: "Status : "
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Label:
            text: "Pending"
            color: [0,84,80,19]
        Widget: # Because of this widget Labels are not in the middle, its not on your drawing tough


<ContainerBox>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        text: 'Label'
        size_hint_y: 0.1
    BoxLayout:
        id: four_horizontals
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        HBoxWidget:
        BoxLayout:
            orientation:'vertical'
            # One solution
            #GridLayout:
            #    cols:1
            #    padding: 100
            #    VBoxWidget1:
            #    VBoxWidget1:
            #    VBoxWidget1:
            #    VBoxWidget1:

            #Second Solution
            BoxLayout:
                #size_hint_y: 0 to 1 - it says how much you reduce height. Now its 1/3 of its parent, because there are 3 boxlayouts. if you set 0.5, it will have 1/3*0.5 and the other 2 boxlayouts takes the height which you took from this one 
            BoxLayout:
                orientation:'vertical'
                VBoxWidget1:
                VBoxWidget1:
                VBoxWidget1:
                VBoxWidget1:
            BoxLayout:
```

python

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.togglebutton import ToggleButton
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class HBoxWidget(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(HBoxWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class VBoxWidget1(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(VBoxWidget1, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class ContainerBox(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ContainerBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ContainerBox() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

**Additional info:**

The way I managed those 4 labels is not really correct way. I will give you hint how to solve it more correctly.
Check https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.floatlayout.html#module-kivy.uix.floatlayout

On BoxLayout, widgets organize themself automaticly - horizontaly or verticaly and they scale based on how much space belongs to them. 
With FloatLayout, there is no restriction so you can position labels as you wish.

In general, if you have changing resolution, its better to solve it with BoxLayouts. If you want more freedom, use FloatLayout, but you will have to manage widget scaling and positioning by yourself

Comment: I was trying other methods too and am getting stuck at the same kind of situation. The distance between the ` VBoxWidget1` is too much. Secondly, the gif is coming at the left corner. It should be in centre of `HBoxWidget`. Right? Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I edited the answer. There are two solutions. I know its not the most pro solution, but this is usually how I solve this kind of problems with kivy layouts.

Comment: According to the last point which you mentioned, changing resolution does makes the difference here. But I get your point. Will try FloatLayout too. Thanks. One more query, how do we set the background of the whole screen? Not a color but an image.

Comment: I will not give you full answer. Just direct you - https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.texture.html . The 'buf' can be numpy_array.tostring(). So you can load image as an numpy array.... After you have texture ready, you draw it on canvas. But thats all in the link